# GDAL_RASTERIO_RESAMPLING error when using QGIS GDAL translate

Tags: qgis, gdal, rasterio, vrt

I have a VRT of a multiband raster layer from Sentinel 2. I converted it to a GTiff using GDAL translate in QGIS 3.10 and, though I received the output I wanted, I got hundreds or thousands of these errors popping up while processing:

```
GDAL_RASTERIO_RESAMPLING = max not supported
```

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: Something in your VRT file or in QGIS asks to use "max" resampling instead of, for example "nearest neighbor" or "average".

Comment: I was about to add a similar thought of that of user30184, without see the exact settings of your rasters. It might be down-sample say a unsigned 32-bit integer to a unsigned 8-bit integer. So what might have been a valid pixel value of 4294967295 has been reduced to 255 and it is simply warning you that max value of the input raster was  too large to be supported by your outgoing format.

Comment: Right, will check what the in and out formats were. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the VRT XML, you can open it in a text editor and copy (include just part of it if it's too big, from the beginning to somehwere after the first closing VRTRasterBand element).